# Unable to get selected option from a select field with a repeater (ASP.net / Sitecore)

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

I am working with an ASP repeater to get the elements from a Sitecore multi-list field (see code below). When the form is submitted, I can't pull the value of the selected option. Trying to add an ID and runat="server" to the  element breaks the code because the repeater also has runat="server".

I'm very new to ASP, but it seems there has to be an option to pull the value of a selected field in a form.

This is the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSubjectSelect" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptSubject_ItemDataBound">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
         <select data-id="select" class="dropdown-component--select">
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <option value="<%# ((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem)["TextSubject"].ToString() %>"><%# ((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem)["TextSubject"].ToString() %></option>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </select>                                    
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that instead of using a repeater this way (to manually build an HTML select input), use an ASP dropdown control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll try that and let you know how it goes.